# How to validate presence of attribute when name is entered but id is passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `foo` with a form.  On the form there is the following:

```
<%= text_field_tag :bar_name, '', id: "bar_name", class: "ajax-typeahead", data: {provide: "typeahead", source: @bar_options} %>
```

Currently, when the user enters the name of a `bar` that is in the db, all is well.  However, if the user enters a name of a `bar` that is not available in the db it causes the following error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/foos_controller.rb:199:in `update'
```

What is the proper validation to disallow this from happening?  Currently I have:

```
validates_presence_of :bar, 
                      :message => 'Please enter full bar name, 
                                   find by typing the first letters in the bar name'
```

Comment: The problem is in your controller, which should only return `Bar` if found by name. Something like `@bar = Bar.find(name: params[:bar_name]) || nil`. What is happening is you're trying to find `Bar` by name, and yet when not found you're trying to access `Bar.id`.

Comment: @DamienRoche, That is the correct solution.  Feel free to convert it to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Great! Sure, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your controller, which should only return `Bar` if found by name. Something like:

`@bar = Bar.find(name: params[:bar_name]) || nil`

You're attempting to find `Bar` by name, and yet when not found you're trying to access `Bar.id`.